# .NET - comma separated appSettings value to list of integers (+ handle empty value)

Tags: .net, string, linq, is-empty

I have following entry in `appSettings`:

```
<add key="blackListedIDs" value="" />
```

In code, I tried to convert this CSV value into list of integers as:

```
var blackList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blackListedIDs"]
                .Split(',')
                .Select(n => int.Parse(n.Trim()))
                .ToList();
```

But it catches an error:

```
Message = "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

It is due to empty string value in `appSettings` key. When I fill it with some data, for example `<add key="blackListedIDs" value="1, 2, 3" />` everything is ok. How to handle empty string value inline, in simplest way, maybe to add handling to LINQ expression above?

Comment: Pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `Split` to remove empty entries. Debug your code to see what value caused the exception

Comment: As I already mentioned in question, exception is caused by empty value in `appSettings` key.  I added `Where` filter (mentioned by Aominè below) into `LINQ` expression and now it works. 

When I pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to Split function, get warning: `"Argumnet 2: cannot convert from StringSplitOptions to 'char'"`

Comment: Add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and you won't get any exceptions. I already posted an answer that shows how this can handle empties, double commas, trailing commas

Answer (score 4):

Use the String.Split overload that allows you to pass the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries option, eg :

```
var blackList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blackListedIDs"]
                .Split(new[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(n => int.Parse(n))
                .ToList();
```

If the input string is empty or whitespace, `Split` won't return anything. This will also handle leading or trailing commas.

You don't need to trim the string either, `int.Parse()` can handle leading or trailing whitespace.

The following code :

```
var items = ",1 , 2 ,".Split(new[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Select(n => int.Parse(n))
                      .ToArray();
```

Will return `1, 2` even though there are spaces, a leading and a trailing separator

Answer (score 2):

You can add a filter to retain only the non empty strings like this:

```
var blackList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blackListedIDs"]
                .Split(',')                 
                .Where(n => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n)) // filter out empty strings                   
                .Select(n => int.Parse(n.Trim()))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: That did the job.